# page permission check with react router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using useRoutes of React Router v6 to render routes, and I want to check permissions every time user access the page .

I found below example,but is there any other way to use a wrapper for each page?
like next middleware.

https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/auth?file=src/App.tsx

about useRoutes : https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/route-objects

this is my code. it works but the problem is that NavBar is also invisible when an unauthorized user approaches.

```
function App() {
...
  const routes: RouteObject[] = [
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <RequireAuth role={"role test"} component={<NavBar />}></RequireAuth>,
      children: [
        { index: true, element: <Home /> },
        {
          path: "/pricing",
          element: <Pricing />,
        },
        {
          path: "/guide",
          element: <Guide />,
        },
        {
          path: "/consult",
          element: <Consult />,
        },
        { path: "*", element:  <Error /> }
      ]
    }
  ];
  let element = useRoutes(routes);
  
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        {element}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Fragment>
  );
```

Comment: You could render the `NavBar` *outside* the auth layout component so it's rendered regardless.

Comment: I'd like to, but I don't know where to place the components. you mean to put it in the children of navbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...the problem is that `NavBar` is also invisible when an unauthorized user
> approaches.

Move the `Navbar` component outside the `routes` configuration so it is always rendered regardless of route or auth status.

```
const routes: RouteObject[] = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <RequireAuth role={"role test"} />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <Home /> },
      {
        path: "/pricing",
        element: <Pricing />,
      },
      {
        path: "/guide",
        element: <Guide />,
      },
      {
        path: "/consult",
        element: <Consult />,
      },
      { path: "*", element:  <Error /> }
    ]
  }
];

function App() {
  ...

  const element = useRoutes(routes);
  
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <NavBar /> // <-- render NavBar outside routes
        {element}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```